# Perform SELECT without Locking Table but don't allow Dirty Reads

Tags: sql-server-2016, locking, concurrency, nolock

Is there a way I can perform a SELECT query which wont lock the table it is reading  but also won't perform dirty reads?

for example, assume Table1 has 100m records:

```
SELECT Col1,
       Col2
FROM   Table1
```

on the default SQL Server isolation level, the query above will block other queries inserting into Table1,

However

```
SELECT Col1,
       Col2
FROM   Table1 WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Will mean other queries are able inserting records. The downside of this is that the query above is susceptible to dirty reads.

Is there a way to get the "good" part of no lock behaviour (no locking) but not the "bad" (dirty reads) and if not, why is this?

Comment: Can you show the code where that select blocks an insert? Also, NOLOCK doesn't mean the query doesn't take out locks, it means the query doesn't respect locks taken by other queries.

Comment: Seems that you are looking for the `SNAPSHOT` isolation level, which is very expensive. I quote from the docs: "SNAPSHOT transactions reading data do not block other transactions from writing data. Transactions writing data do not block SNAPSHOT transactions from reading data."

Comment: Hi @ErikDarling, that was always my understanding until today but https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-the-impact-of-nolock-and-with-nolock-table-hints-in-sql-server/ suggests "The default behaviour in SQL Server is for every query to acquire its own shared lock prior to reading data from a given table. This behaviour ensures that you are only reading committed data. However, the NOLOCK table hint allows you to instruct the query optimiser to read a given table without obtaining an exclusive or shared lock"

Comment: Also, if I run the nolock query above on my large 100m row table and then run sp_whoisactive @get_locks =1 I can see that the query only has a Sch-S lock

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-2017 "No shared locks are issued to prevent other transactions from modifying data read by the current transaction, and exclusive locks set by other transactions do not block the current transaction from reading the locked data. "

Comment: Your requirement sounds exactly like Read Committed Snapshot. Some requisite reading [here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/), [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/read-committed-snapshot-isolation), and [here](https://littlekendra.com/2016/02/18/how-to-choose-rcsi-snapshot-isolation-levels/). And for NOLOCK see [this](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/04/t-sql-queries/the-read-uncommitted-isolation-level) & [this](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/).

Comment: Just remember that everything is a trade-off. RCSI avoids the bad parts of NOLOCK but it's not a free lunch - there is impact to tempdb that has to be tested.